# How to take value from input and take it to AJAX request link?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So I have done this AJAX request with angularJS:

http://jsfiddle.net/c0Lkja0h/1/

When I use link like for example `$http.get('http://api.wunderground.com/api/KEY/forecast/geolookup/conditions/q/San_Francisco.json')` (without '+ city +' in the link) it works great. But when I add that variable, add to `ng-model="city"` and hit submit, then it says

> city is not defined

How can I make it take city name from that input and use it in my newAJAXreq function when I click "Find Weather" button ? Also it would be cool that default link would be with static link (when person first visited the site), and after that city is taken from input if user wants. THANKS!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of things wrong with your approach.

1. Don't name your controller. It should be an anonymous function that take as parameters the modules you want to inject, such as `.controller(function($http){ //do something });` or `.controller(['$http',function($http){ //do something }])` to avoid losing reference to your variables when you minify your js files.
2. Inside your controller, define the function you want that takes as parameter the city, such as `$scope.sendAjax = function(city){ //do something }`. In your view you are gonna call this function with only the argument you need `ng-submit="sendAjax(city)"`
3. Avoid using scope. From the great book AngularJS:Up and Running, by Shyam Seshadri and Brad Green:

> If you used AngularJS prior to 1.2, you might have expected the $scope variable to be injected into the controller, and the variables helloMsg and goodbyeMsg to be set on it. In AngularJS 1.2 and later, there is a new syntax, the controllerAs syntax, which allows us to define the variables on the controller instance using the *this* keyword, and refer to them through the controller from the HTML.
>
> The advantage of this over the earlier syntax is that it makes it explicit in the HTML which variable or function is provided by which controller and which instance of the controller. So with a complicated, nested UI, you don’t need to play a game of “Where’s Waldo?” to find your variables in your codebase. It becomes immediately obvious be‐ cause the controller instance is present in the HTML.

The alternative is in your view use the controller as syntax: `"ng-controller="WeatherController as weather"`, and then always refer to the alias when you need to access Weather Controller scope, such as `ng-submit="weather.sendAjax()"`.

In your controller, you will assign the function to *this*, as in `this.sendAjax = function(){ \\do something }`. A good practice is to assign *this* to another variable, since *this* can get overriden. So in the first line of your controller you can do `var self=this` and refer to the controller as self from this point on, as in `self.sendAjax = function(){ \\do something }`

Comment: Where should I add `$scope.sendAjax = function(city){ //do something }` ? inside my `function($scope,$http)` or after that ?

Comment: in the body of your controller (inside the function($scope,$http))

Comment: Could you plese provide corrected code in my jsfiddle or somewhere ? I would really appreciate that !

Comment: why not, I've updated to the same fiddle, /4. didn't check the rest of your code though, you might have other issues with the api, but the angular logic is ok

Comment: Thanks a lot ! now it works. But there is another issue, maybe you can help with it too. If I input city name that is one and only in the world, it works ok. But if not, it returns an array with all the cities with the same name, and I would like to give some choice if it happens. How can I do that ? Should I add something like a conditional statement before running that function ?

Comment: A conditional statement would work, but you should set it inside your sendAjax function. Javascript is dynamically typed, so it does not matter whether you pass a string or an array as an argument. On the first line in the body of sendAjax function you can check if the argument passed is an array, and if it is, apply some special case. Example: `if (city instanceof Array) { //do something }`